# The optim function returns the initial values provided when gradient gr is used

Tags: r, optimization, gradient

I am getting the initial values when I use the gr argument. I get sensible results without it. Why providing the gr argument causes the optim() function to return the initial values. Here is a replication of the problem.
func_0 the function to optimize and func_1 is its gradient

```
func_0 <- function(mu, mu0, Sigma_inv0, t_z){
    log_theta = mu - log(sum(exp(mu))) # mu is a Kx1 column vector
    f = t(log_theta)%*%t_z # t_z is a Kx1 column vector
    f = -(f - 0.5*t(mu - mu0)%*%Sigma_inv0%*%(mu - mu0))
    return(f)
    }

func_1 <- function(mu, mu0, Sigma_inv0, t_z){ 
    log_sum = log(sum(exp(mu)))
    theta = exp(mu - log_sum)
    df = t_z - sweep(as.matrix(theta), 1, sum(t_z), '*') - Sigma_inv0%*%(mu - mu0)
    return(df)
    }
```

The initial values are:

```
Sigma_inv0 = diag(1, 5)
num_topics_  = 6
mu0 = c(0,0,0,0,0)
mu = c(0.5,0,0.75,0.25,1)
t_z = c(5,4,7,2,10)
```

I apply optim() to these functions as:

```
optim(par = mu, fn = func_0,
  mu0 = mu0, t_z = t_z, Sigma_inv0 = Sigma_inv0,
  method = "CG")$par
```

And here is the sensible output:

```
$par
[1] -0.02084741 -0.19948432  0.27185348 -0.65718095  0.60566111

$value
[1] 42.2506

$counts
function gradient 
     78       33 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Now the same function with the gradient applied:

```
optim(par = mu, fn = func_0, gr = func_1,
  mu0 = mu0, t_z = t_z, Sigma_inv0 = Sigma_inv0,
  method = "CG")$par

$par
[1] 0.50 0.00 0.75 0.25 1.00

$value
[1] 43.47864

$counts
function gradient 
    24        1 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

What is wrong with using the gradient argument? I just get the initial values. I tried ridiculous initial values, and I still get my initial values returned to me.
Thanks in advance!

It has been suggested that the gradient may be wrong. I don't think that is the case. Here is a tentative check with a small mu.

```
> optim(par = mu[1:2], fn = func_0,
+       mu0 = mu0[1:2], t_z = t_z[1:2], Sigma_inv0 = Sigma_inv0[1:2,1:2],
+       method = "CG")

$par
[1]  0.09111349 -0.09111587

$value
[1] 6.192819

$counts
function gradient 
     74       31 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Now, I can compute the gradient, which is zero for the optimum mu.

```
> func_1(c(0.09111349, -0.09111587), mu0[1:2], Sigma_inv0[1:2,1:2], 
t_z[1:2])
             [,1]
[1,] 1.330154e-06
[2,] 1.049846e-06
```

And this is almost zero.
However, with a larger mu, the gradient is no longer close to zero. I confess that I do not know the inner work of optim().

Comment: In 99.9% of all cases you gradient is broken. Without analyzing (not much of an R user and not much info about your task given): either the math is wrong or the types/shapes. Look if there is some easy numerical-differentiation tool available (probably used if you pass no gradient) and check your gradient against it!

Comment: Thank you Sascha! Even if the math were wrong, I should not be getting the initial values returned to me. I should probably be getting the wrong solution, not the initial values. I know the area around the solution is close to being flat. I am sure if it has to do with that fact.

Comment: Are you aware of the internals of those solvers? If not, don't make assumptions about their behaviour. Also: you only posted the result, not the solvers state. Check it! Much can happen because of complex internals and a wrong gradient can kill everything, especially line-searches!

Comment: Sascha! Thank you for helping. I am not sure what you mean by "internals of those solvers?". I just edited the post to give more of the output. I don't know much of optimization algorithms. I was just trying to use the optim() function without studying the algorithm. Can you suggest a reading? Thank you!

Comment: The algorithms are mentioned in the official [docs](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html) and these docs also mention the standard book about this (by internals i mean: how do these optimizers work). The state of 0 is indeed strange (but not completely impossible) and i can't follow your *gradient-checks*. I still recommend checking your gradient vs. num-diff (sorry if you did that; but with my limited R-experience it does not seem so; this step does not involve calling optim) and for fun: run with method="L-BFGS-B" and check out the status again.

Comment: Thank you very much Sascha! I checked my gradient with numerical differentiation function. The grad() function of the numDeriv package, and it confirmed that the gradient is correct. I am happy to have find a way to confirm that my gradient is correct. Thank you for suggesting this check. I needed it; I just wasn't aware of such idea. Also, I used  the "L-BFGS-B" method with the gradient, and it returns the initial values with an error message. The convergence number is 52. I can work without the gradient. I am just curious about the source of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change the gradient sign and you get the answer you want...

```
func_1 <- function(mu, mu0, Sigma_inv0, t_z){

  log_sum = log(sum(exp(mu)))
  theta = exp(mu - log_sum)
  df = (t_z - sweep(as.matrix(theta), 1, sum(t_z), '*') - Sigma_inv0%*%(mu - mu0))*alpha

  return(df)
} 

alpha=-1
optim(par = mu, fn = func_0, gr = func_1,
      mu0 = mu0, t_z = t_z, Sigma_inv0 = Sigma_inv0,control=list(trace=1),
      method = "L-BFGS-B")$par #"CG"
```